# Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.jobRepository': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for th

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am developing a **Spring Batch** project and in this project I am communicating with the **Oracle DB**, but when my main method loading the XML file its giving me the below error. I am really struggling to make it working. Any help ?

It looks to me that some bean not expecting to have a scope step, but debugger doesn't giving any error in detailed.

Error below for reference:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.jobRepository': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
Done
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:98)
    at CustomerFileGenerationMain.main(CustomerFileGenerationMain.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.getContext(StepScope.java:167)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    ... 6 more
```

XML file -

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:configs/default/scheduler.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

    <bean id="stepScope" class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
        <property name="autoProxy" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="MPDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXXXXXX1" />
        <property name="username" value="XXXXXX"/>
        <property name="password" value="XXXXXXX" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean" scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="MPDataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="ORACLE" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>


    <batch:job id="MyJob">
        <batch:step id="initContextStep"  next="customerDecision">
            <batch:tasklet ref="AAAATasklet" />
        </batch:step>
        <batch:decision id="customerDecision" decider="customerDecider">
            <batch:next on="FAILURE" to="ABCStep" />
            <batch:next on="SUCCESS" to="ABCCache" /> 
        </batch:decision>
        <batch:step id="ABCCache" next="masterStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="ABCLoader" />
        </batch:step>

        <batch:step id="masterStep" next="updateFileStatusStep">
            <partition step="ABCFileStep" partitioner="ABCPartitioner">
                <handler grid-size="40" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
            </partition>
        </batch:step>

        <batch:step id ="ABCStep"  next = "updateFileStatusStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="KKKFileTasklet" />
        </batch:step>

        <batch:step id="updateFileStatusStep" next = "consolidateEmailStep" >
            <batch:tasklet ref="updateStausTasklet" />
        </batch:step>   

        <batch:step id="consolidateEmailStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="consolidatedEmailTasklet" />
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>


    <bean id="consolidatedEmailTasklet" class="com.test.ConsolidatedEmailTasklet" scope="step">
        <property name="jobInstanceName" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobInstance.jobName}"></property>
        <property name="jobInstanceId" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobId}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ABCLoader" class="com.test.ABCMappingCache" scope="step">
        <property name="executionContext" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="40" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="40" />
        <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
    </bean>


    <batch:step id="ABCFileStep" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="ABCReader" processor="ABCProcessor" writer="ABCWriter" commit-interval="5000" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>

    <bean id="ABCWriter" class="com.test.writer.ABCWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="jobInstanceName" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobInstance.jobName}"></property>
        <property name="jobInstanceId" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobId}"></property>
        <property name="executionContext" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ABCMapping" class="com.test.ABCMapping" scope="step">
        <property name="executionContext" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ABCProcessor" class="com.test.ABCProcessor" scope="step">
        <property name="jobInstanceName" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobInstance.jobName}"></property>
        <property name="jobInstanceId" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobId}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ABCReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="MPDataSource" />
        <property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="false" />
        <property name="fetchSize" value="500" />
        <property name="sql"><value>    <![CDATA[ SELECT * FROM ABC ]]></value></property>

        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.test.ABCRowMapper" />
        </property>
        <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="statementSetter" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="statementSetter" class="org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter" scope="step">
        <property name="parameters">
            <list>
                <value>#{stepExecutionContext[ica]}</value>
                <value>#{stepExecutionContext[histDays]}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="ABCPartitioner" class="com.test.ABCPartitioner" scope="step">
        <property name="executionContext" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="generateFileScheduler" class="com.test.GenerateFileScheduler" />

    <bean id="fileGenerationDAO" class="com.test.FileGenerationRulesDao">
        <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="MPDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ABCExclusionDAO" class="com.mastercard.ess.eds.core.dao.ABCExclusionDAO">
        <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="MPDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="OOOScheduler" method="updateCache" cron="0 0 0/1 * * ?" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <bean id="OOOScheduler"
        class="com.test.FileGenerationRulesCache">
    </bean>

    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="VVVVCacheScheduler" method="updateListOfExcludedBrands" cron="0 0 0/1 * * ?" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <bean id="VVVVCacheScheduler" class="com.test.BrandExclusionCache"></bean>

    <bean id="lastBatchJobRunDao" class="com.test.dao.LastBatchJobRunDao">
        <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="MPDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="DDDStausTasklet" class="com.test.DDDStausTasklet" scope="step" >
        <property name="jobInstanceName" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobInstance.jobName}"></property>
        <property name="jobInstanceId" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobId}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="KKKFileTasklet" class="com.Testtasklet.KKKFileTasklet" scope="step">
        <property name="jobInstanceName" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobInstance.jobName}"></property>
        <property name="jobInstanceId" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobId}"></property>
        <property name="executionContext" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerDecider" class ="com.test.CustomerDecider" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Why is your `JobRepository` even job scoped? That is a central infrastructure component and shouldn't be scoped.

Comment: @ M. Deinum - Thanks error gone..